# print python counter of GPIO pin output at set intervals

Tags: python, counter, raspberry-pi

I'm having a problem with a task i'm doing with an anemometer that works using a switch every revolution.  The task is using a raspberry pi therefore the language is in python.

What I am trying to do is print a counter value every 10 seconds.  However I don't want it to be a delay where nothing happens during the 10 second wait.  Basically I want the number of times a switch is pressed in 10 seconds printed to me every 10 seconds.

Sorry if that was vague any extra info needed just ask.

```
While True:
    stuff = dio.readU8(portB)
    dio.write8(portA, stuff)

    if stuff == 192:
        print ('on')
    else:
        print ('off')
```

This is what it currently does simply constantly print its state either on or off I havn't yet implemented a counter as I am unsure the way it works in python and am wondering if it is similar to other languages i'm new to python I only usually use Java.  The above code works even though values may look weird.

Comment: It would be useful if you showed the code you've tried so far, and explained why it is not working.

Comment: sorry I will add that when im back  to my computer asap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the time module to watch the time, put it in at the end of the event catching code to see if 10+ seconds has passed.

something like...

```
import time

last_time = time.time()
#start of event catching loop

if time.time() - last_time >= 10
   print buttonCountVariable
   last_time = time.time()
```

Comment: Thank you very much that's exactly what I needed I'd vote you up but I only have 12 rep.